# bigquery data location transfer

Tags: dataset, storage, google-bigquery

Because of the availability of storing data in EU now we decided that we would like to change some of our datasets which are currently stored in US to EU. 
However we can't find any efficiënt way of transfering the datasets. (Don't want to export data sets and import them again in EU for each set).

Is there any efficiënt way of doing this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this (that I know of at least) automatically.

You will indeed need to export and then re-import. There might be a way to get this streamlined by proposing it as a Feature Request [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list).